# How do I declare global variables when using tsc to typecheck my javascript?

Tags: javascript, types, tsc

I'm trying to use the TypeScript compiler, `tsc`, to do type checking on a well annotated JavaScript file. This file makes use of a couple of global variables that are loaded through other scripts, for the sake of simplicity, we'll work with just one global variable `L` (which is for Leaflet).

First, I run the command:

```
tsc --allowJs --checkJs mysource.js --outfile out.js --lib dom,es2015
```

Which produces the output:

```
mysource.js:15:15 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'L'.

15 const myMap = L.map('mapid')
```

In this case `L` is a global variable that is defined when I import the Leaflet JavaScript code earlier in the HTML file.

Other tools such as [StandardJS](https://standardjs.com/) provide a syntax to declare global variables, but I can't figure out how to do it with `tsc`. In the case of standard, I just have a line that states:

```
/* global L */
```

To be clear, I'm not using `tsc` because I'm using TypeScript, I'm only using it because it has the ability to do type checking on JavaScript source files. I just want another check to make sure that my types match up in my JavaScript file.